# Get access to original request, before load balancer, on Heroku

Tags: express, heroku

***EDIT:*** for posterity - it turns out I made a mistake - the issue wasn't Heroku getting rid of the original URL, but rather our API CDN / gateway kinda thing that sits in front of Heroku and takes all incoming API traffic, then returns the cached version or redirects it to the relevant heroku service.

By the time a request hits our express app on Heroku, the req object from express no longer resembles the original request sent by the browser, but instead is the request sent on from Heroku's load balancer to our app.

I need access to properties of the original request that hit the load balancer. How do I do this with Heroku?

Here's some example things I've tried, all of which are wrong - protocol should be `https` and domain should be eg. `example.com`:

`req.protocol`: http
`req.headers['X-Forwarded-Proto']`: http
`req.hostname`:sheltered-storm-123.herokuspace.com
`req.headers.host`: sheltered-storm-123.herokuspace.com
`req.header('host')`: sheltered-storm-123.herokuspace.com
`req.headers['X-Forwarded-Host']`: undefined

What I want to do is always use the www version of the URL, and redirect eg. `http://example.com/my-page` to `http://www.example.com/my-page`

Exact code (express middleware) is:

```
export default function redirectWww(req, res, next) {
  var host = req.header('host')
  if (host.match(/^www\..*/i)) {
    next()
  } else {
    res.redirect(301, `${req.protocol}://www.${host}${req.originalUrl}`)
  }
}
```

Comment: A little more explanation around _why_ you'd want these would be good to add here. Are you using them to alter what the app does, for instance? If so, how?

Comment: I've added more info. Looking at this point like we'll have to do the redirect in front of Heroku somewhere, rather than in the express app. Would love to be proven wrong though.

Comment: for posterity: it turns out I made a mistake - the issue wasn't Heroku getting rid of the original URL, but rather our API CDN / gateway kinda thing that sits in front of Heroku and takes all incoming API traffic, then returns the cached version or redirects it to the relevant heroku service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just want the protocol and hostnames, these can be found with the [`req.protocol`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.protocol) and [`req.hostname`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.hostname) variables in any express http handler (a `req, res, next` function).

If you're looking for other headers, you might be out of luck. Heroku is a locked down environment made to get you going quickly, the more control you want, the more you're probably going to need to move to something more self-managed. [Heroku's load balancer / http routing docs show the headers they append](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#heroku-headers) but the ones you've listed as required are not ones they provide.

Comment: req.protocol and req.hostname both contain the values post-load-balancer. Still can't seem to find any way to get to what came from the browser.

I'll accept your answer if no one comes back with a way to get the original request... even though it seems like a pretty critical requirement for a web host to be missing...

Comment: Heroku are a convenience service, and you pay for that with less freedom and higher prices. If you really need this functionality I'd suggest moving to a more managed solution on something like DigitalOcean, AWS, GCP etc as Heroku provide no means of LB configuration at the moment (or at least it isn't documented).

Comment: for posterity: it turns out I made a mistake - the issue wasn't Heroku getting rid of the original URL, but rather our API CDN / gateway kinda thing that sits in front of Heroku and takes all incoming API traffic, then returns the cached version or redirects it to the relevant heroku service.